# Get some text with CURL and parse only the variables inside with PHP

Tags: php, curl

PHP is getting external text into a variable with GET CURL from another domain like: https://somedomain.com/file.txt

This **file.txt** contains some text and variables inside like:

> Welcome to our $STORENAME store, $CUSTOMERNAME
>
> Our store is located at $STOREADDRESS in somewhere.

You see the text contains some variables inside.

When I get the text in the PHP file in my domain like:
https://example.com/emailer.php

This **emailer.php** file is:

```
<?php
# Defining variables to use in the text we acquire:
$STORENAME = "candy";
$CUSTOMERNAME = "William";
$STOREADDRESS = "123 Store Street";

# Get the text from another domain:
$CURL = curl_init();
curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_URL, "https://somedomain.com/file.txt");
curl_setopt($CURL, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
$result = curl_exec($CURL);

echo "$result";
```

> **Actual Result:**
>
> Welcome to our $STORENAME store, $CUSTOMERNAME
>
> Our store is located at $STOREADDRESS in somewhere.
>
> **Expected Result:**
>
> Welcome to our candy store, William
>
> Our store is located at 123 Store Street in somewhere.

How to get PHP to parse the variables, not treat them like text?

And **without using** functions like eval() or without enabling remote include with "allow_url_include" or without regex or without explode to break text and re-merge...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your best option is to use str_replace in this situation, like this:

```
<?php

$STORENAME = "candy";
$CUSTOMERNAME = "William";
$STOREADDRESS = "123 Store Street";

$result = 'Welcome to our $STORENAME store, $CUSTOMERNAME<br>
Our store is located at $STOREADDRESS in somewhere.';

$result = str_replace(
    array('$STORENAME','$CUSTOMERNAME','$STOREADDRESS'),
    array($STORENAME,$CUSTOMERNAME,$STOREADDRESS),
    $result
);

echo $result;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `str_replace` with your defined key/value pairs:

```
# Defining variables to use in the text we acquire:
$replacement_array = array(
    '$STORENAME' => "candy",
    '$CUSTOMERNAME' => "William",
    '$STOREADDRESS' => "123 Store Street"
);

# Get the text from another domain:


// PUT YOUR CURL CODE HERE - FOR THIS EXAMPLE WE'LL JUST USE $message

$message = '
Welcome to our $STORENAME store, $CUSTOMERNAME

Our store is located at $STOREADDRESS in somewhere.
';


# Define your replacement array
echo str_replace(array_keys($replacement_array), $replacement_array, $message);
```

Example: https://eval.in/861140